# Restriction of a continuous function is continuous but Extension of a continuous function need not be continuous.Why?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that restriction of a continuous function is continues but how to prove this.Is there any proof or counter example.

Comment: Depends on what an "extension" is. You could for example take $$f\colon [0,\infty)\to\mathbb R,\qquad x\mapsto f(x)=\sqrt x$$ and "extend" it to $$\tilde f\colon (-\infty,\infty)\to\mathbb R,\qquad x\mapsto f(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt x,&\text{for }x\geq 0\\-1,&\text{for }x<0\end{cases}.$$ This would be an extension, but it's obviously not continuous, where $f$ itself is continuous.

Comment: Not following.  What's an extension of a function?  Just some function that coincides on the smaller region?  Why would that have to be continuous?

Comment: Can you edit your post for clarity?  As it stands, it is not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: Three different spellings of "continuous" in the title.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Comment: Do you know what a Restriction of function and Extension of a function is?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it for you.